# select all and truncate redis database

Tags: node.js, redis, nosql

I'm looking for something similar to BLPOP, but instead of element I want to get them all run running over them in a loop.
It means that I want to get all the records of redis collection, and truncate it.

Comment: Why not just LRANGE+DEL?

Comment: I create a lot a records, in that case I may delete some unread records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a LUA script to do the LRANGE+DEL atomically.

Or use [RENAME](http://redis.io/commands/rename) to move the list to a temporary key which you will use to process the data.

```
RENAME yourlist temp-list
LRANGE temp-list 0 -1
... process the list
DEL temp-list
```

Comment: Just making sure, if I rename the list, and than try to add to the original list name some data, it will auto create a list with the original name ?